# Parse issue on Unity 5.1.1 with IL2CPP

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

My team is working on a project with Unity 5.1.1. We are using Parse to store data online. Working on the editor is fine. Building a project with Mono as scripting backend has no problem. But building with IL2CPP causes a problem.

When Parse is initialised, there will be an error as below

*missingMethodException: Method not found: 'Default constructor not found...ctor() of Parse.PlatformHooks'.*

I did research and find out that normally this error would occur if the project has optimisation turned on, but it is off for my project

I have lost 2 days trying to fix this problem but found no solution yet

Comment: I would hazard a guess and say that's caused by the stripping. If you disable stripping, does the problems still persist?

Comment: @Bart Thanks for your opinion. You can check out my player settings here - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0vWR6nY09_wU0syZEJ1SDI2OWM 
I have turned off all stripping options and the problem still persists

Answer (score 2):

With the IL2CPP scripting backend, some level of stripping is always enabled, even when the "Stripping Level" option is set to a value of "Disabled". We do this to keep the binary size reasonable.

We might be changing this behavior soon, and allow stripping to really be disabled, but in the meantime, you can probably work around the issue.

You can use a link.xml file for require the Unity stripping code to keep certain types. See the documentation here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html

Based on the error message though, I'm guessing that you want something like this:

```
<linker>
       <assembly fullname="Parse">
               <type fullname="Parse.PlatformHooks" preserve="all"/>
       </assembly>
</linker>
```

Comment: Thank you for you work around. The file link.xml works for me for local build. The problem is, it doesn't work with Unity Cloud Build. I have also opened a thread in Unity Forum here

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/problem-with-link-xml.337285/

The build I have from Cloud Build behaves strange with link.xml, so I am wondering if Cloud Build supports link.xml?

Comment: I can't say much about Cloud Build, but I would expect this to work. I think asking in the forum is the proper solution.

Comment: Thank you @Josh. I have tried with 4 projects, 2 doesn't have problem with  link.xml but the other 2 have. Hope I will get the proper solution from the forum :)